# Extending Support for Basic Authentication for EWS

Tags: graph, oauth, exchangewebservices

With many customers otherwise focused on other priorities due to COVID19 related issues, is there any potential for MSFT extending the support date for Basic Auth for EWS services?

The current date is mid-October 2020 and I know many banks are in a difficult position to try and migrate to Graph since it's new for most developers.

Comment: As useful as this information is, it's a customer service issue, and thus not actually about programming as defined in the Help Centre.

Answer (score 1):

Its already been announced

> In response to the COVID-19 crisis and knowing that priorities have changed for many of our customers we have decided to postpone disabling Basic Authentication in Exchange Online for those tenants still actively using it until the second half of 2021

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-april-2020-update/ba-p/1275508